# Angular: Error no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm"

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms

I have tried importing the FormsModule and NgForm modules as well as adding the FormsModule to the imports array.

Below is my code:

```
//our root app component
import { Component, NgModule, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule, NgForm} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <form #searchForm="ngForm">
  <input type="text" required [(ngModel)]="model.search" ngControl="search" #inputSearch="ngForm">
  <p class="error" [hidden]="inputSearch.valid"> This input is required</p>


  </form>

  `,
  styles: [`
  .error {
    color: red;
    font-size: 11px;
  }
  `]
})
export class App {
  public model = {
    search: "" 
  }

  constructor() {

  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [App],
  bootstrap: [App],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And below is an error printout:

> runtime.9ff156e16d788666a54a.js:16 Error: Template parse errors:
>   **There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm"** ("   ]#searchForm="ngForm">      ]#inputSearch="ngForm">    This input is required
>
> "):
>   ng:///AppModule/App.html@2:76 Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a
>   known property of 'input'. ("      ][(ngModel)]="model.search"
>   ngControl="search" #inputSearch="ngForm">   https://run.plnkr.co/rhpwnL6UIQwCFOKZ/src/main.js   Loading
>   https://run.plnkr.co/rhpwnL6UIQwCFOKZ/src/main.js f @
>   runtime.9ff156e16d788666a54a.js:16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error was caused by this line:

```
#inputSearch="ngForm"
```

This is the correct line:

```
#inputSearch="ngModel"
```

Here is the working example. When you use ngModel within the form tag you also need to provide value for the "name" attribute.

```
  <form #searchForm="ngForm">
  <input type="text" required name="search" [(ngModel)]="model.search"  #inputSearch="ngModel">
  <p class="error" [hidden]="inputSearch.valid"> This input is required</p>
  </form>
```

Comment: is this a change to the way angular is used? I ask because I am following videos from a course.

Comment: It is not such change. You were trying to assign ngForm to a template variable outside of the form tag.

Comment: You can read more about the NgForm usage here: https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm. Please rate and accept my answer if it helped you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

This ng-directive error is faced when you have not imported the ng-module in your **app.component.ts** or your component is not imported and added into the declarations of **@NgModule({})**

Answer (score 1):

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

  [...]

 @NgModule({
   imports: [
      [...]
     FormsModule
    ],
    [...]
  })
```

Comment: Please explain how this improves on the accepted answer. Just a code snippet doesn't mean much.

Comment: import { FormsModule } from @angular/forms  in your component, this is the solution of [Error no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm"].